# convert each row of a pandas table to list and add to table

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert each row into a list and insert as a new column.
For example, I start with the following table:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  8  3  2  5
1  1  1  2  2  4
2  0  8  9  6  4
3  2  7  6  1  9
4  8  9  1  5  6
```

and would like to get:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  test
0  0  8  3  2  5  [0, 8, 3, 2, 5]
1  1  1  2  2  4  [1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
2  0  8  9  6  4  [0, 8, 9, 6, 4]
3  2  7  6  1  9  [2, 7, 6, 1, 9]
4  8  9  1  5  6  [8, 9, 1, 5, 6]
```

Here is my code snippet which I expected to achieve exactly that, only it doesn't.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)))
df['list'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
In [127]: df['test'] = df.values.tolist()

In [128]: df
Out[128]: 
   0  1  2  3  4             test
0  0  8  3  2  5  [0, 8, 3, 2, 5]
1  1  1  2  2  4  [1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
2  0  8  9  6  4  [0, 8, 9, 6, 4]
3  2  7  6  1  9  [2, 7, 6, 1, 9]
4  8  9  1  5  6  [8, 9, 1, 5, 6]
```

Comment: +1 for a correct answer. But I think it behooves us to comment that storing lists in a dataframe is usually a poor design choice. You give up all vectorised functionality.

Comment: Why does assigning `df.values.tolist()` work vs. `df.values` which raises `ValueError`?